# How to stick this image to the bottom of the div

Tags: css

I would like this image(smaller - grey one) to stay at the bottom of its `div`(meadow image) when the window is resized.. I have tried with auto values on attributes but I guess it has something to do with positioning, can't figure out what it is exactly..any ideas maybe? Thanks a tonne!

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zoEYgP

```css
.images {
  background: url("http://kingofwallpapers.com/meadow/meadow-008.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 780px;
  /*position: relative;*/

}
.smaller {
  text-align: center;
}
.smaller img {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -280px;
}
@media screen and(max-width: 768px) {
  .images {
    height: auto;
    /*position: relative;*/
  }
  .smaller img {
    width: 80%;
    /*height: auto;*/
    /*margin-bottom: 0px;*/
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="images">
  <div class="smaller">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97500&w=400&h=500" alt="">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Could you give more details about what kind of output you are looking for when you resize screen below 768px.

Comment: @Tushar I would just like the grey image to be let's say 80% width(or any other width) while keeping the aspect ratio, and stick it to the bottom of the meadow image. I'm looking for a IE8+ solution,but IE9+ is still fine

Answer (score 1):

see the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBoNQq?editors=1100), I made `smaller .image` `position: absolute` and tweak some css aound

```css
.images {
  background: url("http://kingofwallpapers.com/meadow/meadow-008.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 768px;
  /*height: 100vh;*/
  min-height: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}


.smaller img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    right: 0;
}

@media screen and(max-width: 768px) {
  .images {
    height: 100vh;
    //position: relative;
  }
  .smaller img {
    //width: 80%;
    //height: auto;
    //margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="images">
  <div class="smaller">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97500&w=400&h=500" alt="">
  </div>
</section>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis nulla laboriosam laborum sapiente sit voluptate voluptatum, velit eius quam minus natus incidunt omnis quidem cupiditate, maxime, ex reprehenderit minima enim!</p>
```

Comment: interesting solution, thank you, I will try to incorporate it into my page